# Passing model data to partial view after updating model again

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I am having a main view and few partial views.

The main view is something which displays the list of registered users like this :
[image]

The main view code :

```
@model WebApplication9.Models.User

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link ref="~/Styles/UserManagement.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="btnDefineTraj" onclick="AddUserBtnClick()" id="button1">Create New User</button>
    </p>

    <div hidden id="divAddUser" title="Add new user" style="border-radius: 7px">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/UserManagement/CreateUser.cshtml")
    </div>

        <div hidden id="divEditUser" title="Edit user" style="border-radius: 7px">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/UserManagement/EditUser.cshtml", Model)
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>UserID
            </th>
            <th>Username
            </th>
            <th>Password
            </th>
            <th>FirstName
            </th>
            <th>LastName
            </th>
            <th>DisplayName
            </th>
            <th>Email
            </th>
            <th>Pref. Language
            </th>
            <th>CreatedBy
            </th>
            <th>CreatedTime
            </th>
            <th>ModifiedTime
            </th>
            <th>IsAdmin
            </th>
            <th>IsActive
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.usersList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.password)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.displayName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.languagePreference)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.createdBy)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.createdTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modifiedTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isAdmin)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isActive)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="btnEditUser" onclick="EditUserBtnClick(@item.userId)" id="buttonEdit">
                        <img src="~/Images/edit-icon.png" width="20" height="20" />
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="btnDeleteUser" onclick="DeleteUserBtnClick(@item.userId)" id="buttonDelete">
                        <img src="~/Images/delete-icon.png" width="20" height="20" /></button>
                    @*                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { id=item.userId } ) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new { id=item.userId })*@
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My model class `User` code is :

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string passWord { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string emailID { get; set; }
    public string languagePreference { get; set; }
    public bool isAdministrator { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<usermaster> usersList{ get; set; }
    public usermaster EditUserData { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the table is loaded from `usersList` in the model.
Now I am trying to implement the edit user functionality. When user clicks on edit button I am opening a partial view :

```
<div hidden id="divEditUser" title="Edit user" style="border-radius: 7px">
@Html.Partial("~/Views/UserManagement/EditUser.cshtml", Model)
</div>
```

by passing the id to the controller and getting back the user data so that it can be displayed in the new partial view

```
function EditUserBtnClick(userid) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UserManagement/EditUser",
    data: JSON.stringify({ userID: userid }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (edituserDataObj) {
        if (msg != null) {
            $("#divEditUser").dialog({ width: 350 });
        }
        else {
            $('#lblResult').val("Failed to delete user.");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        return "error";
    }
});
```

I am getting the `edituserDataObj` properly here. But I am not sure how to pass it to the partial view `EditUser.cshtml`. I tried to edit the model by adding the new edit user data to a model class property `public usermaster EditUserData { get; set; }`. But when I access this from my partial view, the data is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditUser(int userID)
{
    var user = DBManager.Instance.GetUserData(userID);
    return Json(user);
}
```

Is there any way to pass the edit user data to the partial view?

Comment: You already have all the values you need in the view (from the table) so there is no need to call a server method to get it. You view should include a form for a 'default' user and then when you click on the edit link, get the values from the corresponding table row and update the corresponding form controls. Then when you post the values (using ajax), update the text in the corresponding row with the edited values.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Sorry I did not get this point : **You view should include a form for a 'default' user and then when you click on the edit link, get the values from the corresponding table row and update the corresponding form controls.**. Did you mean accessing each control inside the partial view and setting its value like  `$("#divEditUser").$("#username").val() = tablerow.username;`

Comment: Inside the js function I did this to get the row, but it doesn't work `var editUserdata = @Model.usersList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userId == edituserID);`

Comment: Have a look at the (very basic) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) to understand what I mean

Comment: And FGS, don't include the passwords in your table!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok. I checked the fiddle. I did not get the point. Is it possible to pass the id as well as the model to the partial view? Currently I am doing like this `@Html.Partial("~/Views/UserManagement/EditUser.cshtml", Model)`

Comment: I still don't get how to pass mix up javascript and asp code. when the edit button is clicked, I have the @item with me...Even I cant pass that entire item, but I am able to pass @item.userID to the JS function. In that function, i don't know how to get the `item` from `List<users>` enumerable in the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127770/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-vivi).